# Pass user defined environment variable to tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I am using the eclipse for web application coding. Within this I passed environment variable like :

1. Project--> Run as --> Run Configuration. And selected Environment tab.
2. Add new environment variable with name `APP_MASTER_PASSWORD` and its value.

I can access this value in java code as `System.getenv("APP_MASTER_PASSWORD")`.

But now I want to pass this environment variable to tomcat and access it in application instead of passing thru eclipse.

So how can I pass such variable to tomcat?

I googled about it. But I didn't get any solution.

Comment: Are there no options using a Tomcat vhost? These environment settings are not handy if you have multiple copies of the app running. I believe they're called "environment entries"?

Comment: On Tomcat 8.5.51 provided in Amazon Linux repos, I had to append the env-var declaration to `/usr/libexec/tomcat/preamble`; creating `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh` didn't work (in above distro `CATALINA_BASE=/usr/share/tomcat`)

Answer (score 58):

You can use `setenv.bat` or `.sh` to pass the environment variables to the Tomcat.

Create `CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.bat` or `.sh` file and put the following line in it, and then start the Tomcat.

On Windows:

```
set APP_MASTER_PASSWORD=foo
```

On Unix like systems:

```
export APP_MASTER_PASSWORD=foo
```

Comment: this is the case specific for Ubuntu I believe. For Red Hat for example, you can edit CATALINA_HOME/tomcat7.conf

Comment: This is a little late but... According to [Tomcat's documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) , creating the setenv.sh should work for any flavor of Unix. The catalina.sh script will check to see if setenv.sh exists, if so, execute it during the startup process.

Comment: `catalina.sh` checks for both `CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh` and `CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh`, and executes them, if present.

Comment: You can create a setenv.sh script, if it is not already there

Comment: This did not work for me. What did work was editing the /etc/tomcat9/tomcat9.conf file and adding the key=value to the end of that file.

Answer (score 21):

You should use System property instead of environment variable for this case. Edit your tomcat scripts for JAVA_OPTS and add property like:

`-DAPP_MASTER_PASSWORD=foo`

and in your code, write

`System.getProperty("APP_MASTER_PASSWORD");`

You can do this in Eclipse as well, instead of JAVA_OPTS, copy the line in VM parameters inside run configurations.

Answer (score 11):

Environment Entries specified by `<Environment>` markup are JNDI, accessible using [InitialContext.lookup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html#lookup%28java.lang.String%29) under `java:/comp/env`. You can specify environment properties to the [JNDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/source.html) by using the environment parameter to the [InitialContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html#InitialContext%28java.util.Hashtable%29) constructor and [application resource files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/source.html#APPRES).

`System.getEnv()` is about system environment variables of the tomcat process itself.

To set an environment variable using bash command :
`export TOMCAT_OPTS=-Dmy.bar=foo`
and start the Tomcat :
`./startup.sh`
To retrieve the value of System property `bar` use `System.getProperty()`. `System.getEnv()` can be used to retrieve the environment variable i.e. `TOMCAT_OPTS`.

Comment: Today it's CATALOINA_OPTS - but apart form that this was what helped me just now!

Answer (score 9):

**Environment variables** can be set, by creating a `setenv.bat` (windows) or `setenv.sh` (unix) file in the `bin` folder of your tomcat installation directory. However, environment variables will not be accessabile from within your code.

**System properties** are set by `-D` arguments of the java process. You can define java starting arguments in the environment variable `JAVA_OPTS`.

My suggestions is the **combination** of these two mechanisms. In your `apache-tomcat-0.0.0\bin\setenv.bat` write:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-DAPP_MASTER_PASSWORD=password1
```

and in your Java code write:

```
System.getProperty("APP_MASTER_PASSWORD")
```

Answer (score 5):

For Unix & Mac systems, Go to /bin/setenv.sh inside tomcat folder

Add the below line

`export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DAPP_MASTER_PASSWORD=mypass"`

Now `System.getProperty("APP_MASTER_PASSWORD")` will return `"mypass"`

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting your Tomcat from Eclipse ("Servers" view) then you should have a "Run/Run Configuration" (menu) entry called "Apache Tomcat / Tomcat …". When you select this entry in the list of run configurations you get a window with several tabs, one of which is labeled "Environment". There you can configure environment variables for your Tomcat. Be sure to restart Tomcat afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

### My recipe to fix it:

1. DID NOT WORK >> Set as system environment variable: I had set the environment variable in my mac `bash_profile`, however, Tomcat did not see that variable.
2. DID NOT WORK >> setenv.sh: Apache's recommendation was to have user-defined environment variables in `setenv.sh` file and I did that.
3. **THIS WORKED!!** >> After a little research into Tomcat startup scripts, I found that environment variables set using `setenv.sh` are lost during the startup.  So I had to edit my `catalina.sh` against the recommendation of Apache and that did the trick.

Add your `-DUSER_DEFINED` variable in the run command in `catalina.sh`.

```
eval exec "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
  -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" \
  -Djava.security.manager \
  -Djava.security.policy=="\"$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.policy\"" \
  -Dcatalina.base="\"$CATALINA_BASE\"" \
  -Dcatalina.home="\"$CATALINA_HOME\"" \
  -Djava.io.tmpdir="\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"" \
  -DUSER_DEFINED="$USER_DEFINED" \
  org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
```

P.S:  This problem could have been local to my computer.  Others would have different problems. Adding my answer to this post just in case anyone is still facing issues with Tomcat not seeing the environment vars after trying out all recommended approaches.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Windows, if you can't find setenv.bat, in the 2nd line of catalina.bat (after @echo off) add this:
SET APP_MASTER_PASSWORD=foo

May not be the best approach, but works

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through various solutions but none of them worked. Finally I found the tomcat documentation https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt.
You can use setenv.bat or .sh for passing the environment variables to the Tomcat. setenv will not be present by default, it should be created inside CATALINA_BASE/bin.
Configure your environment variable like below in setenv.bat:

`set "JRE_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre6"`