# How do I use a given application.properties file when deploying a .war on Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have been tasked to deploy a ROOT.war app on Apache Tomcat. Here's what the ROOT.war file looks like on the inside:

[image: ROOT.war file structure]

The app I was told uses a Postgresql as its database. I already have sorted that one out.

I just want to know how to run this app on Apache Tomcat using this application.properties configuration file they have provided. Here's what it looks like:

[image: application.properties config]

Thank you very much and regards,
Jeremy

Comment: Try placing the `application.properties` file inside `classes/resources` directory

Comment: Hello @R.G thank you very much for your help. But unfortunately, I still can't make it work. Tomcat at port 8080 still throws me a 404 not found error.

Comment: how did you confirm the app was deployed correctly and the URL you are hitting is as expected ? localhost:8080/ROOT returns 404 is it ?

Comment: I am not entirely sure that the application has been deployed correctly. What I tried to do is check the *catalina.log* inside the Tomcat installation directory. And this line in the log caught my eye and what made me think that the location of the application.properties file is the problem.

Comment: `2020-03-06 17:49:20.679  WARN 9710 --- [ost-startStop-1] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [asia.edusuite.sample.Application]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'property.location' in value "file:${property.location}/application.properties"`

Comment: Yes, I have been checking the application on localhost:8080 and localhost:8080/ROOT

Comment: Could you try providing an environment variable `property.location=resources` , place the `application.properties` within `classes/resources directory` . May be this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23957805/4214241) will give you hints on how to do it

Comment: or may be this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17019233/4214241)

Answer (score 0):

There are may ways to specify the location of the `application.properties` file. See [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config) for full list of how properties are loaded.

As described in section [2.3. Application Property Files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files):

> SpringApplication loads properties from application.properties files in the following locations and adds them to the Spring Environment:
>
> - A `/config` subdirectory of the current directory
> - The current directory
> - A classpath `/config` package
> - The classpath root

It goes on to say:

> If you do not like `application.properties` as the configuration file name, you can switch to another file name by specifying a `spring.config.name` environment property. You can also refer to an explicit location by using the `spring.config.location` environment property (which is a comma-separated list of directory locations or file paths).

Of the many options, I'd highlight:

- ***Recommended:*** According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44697239/5221149), you can specify the location in the Tomcat context XML file, although that is not explicitly specified in the Spring documentation:

  ```xml
  <Context>
      <Parameter name="spring.config.location" value="file:/path/to/config/folder" />
  </Context>
  ```
- Modify the `.war` file and place the file in the `WEB-INF/classes/config` or `WEB-INF/classes` folder.
- If you can specify the working directory for the running Tomcat, place the file there or in a `config` sub-folder.
- If you can specify a JVM option for the running Tomcat, add `-Dspring.config.location=file:/path/to/config/folder`, and place the file there.