# Liquibase: Cannot find changelog location

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, liquibase

Liquibase is searching for changelog under `db/changelog/db/db-changelog-master.yaml` but the right path is `db/changelog/db/db-changelog-master.xml`
I have add `spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml` to my application.properties file, it works when running under Intellij but not when packaged as a war and running with Tomcat.
Is there a configuration that may overwrite application.properties or is my application.properties not taken into account?

Comment: First make sure you are loading your application.properties when deploying as war https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60569013/how-do-i-use-a-given-application-properties-file-when-deploying-a-war-on-apache

Comment: so I have tried to run my war locally and it finds application.properties, it finds my changelog.xml, the problem is only when running with Tomcat

Comment: remove leading "/": spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml